# Access blender interactive python shell from terminal

Tags: python, command-line

Is it possible to get access to the blender interactive python shell from a terminal? I know I can start a python script with the the following command

```
blender --background --python script.py
```

But what i want is to get the actual shell that i can type in the terminal something like

```
>>> bpy.ops.active_object.mode
'OBJECT'
```

and get the result immediatly like in the normal python interactive shell

Comment: oh, i can do that with --python-console. I haven't seen that

Comment: Feel free to add that as an answer :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is to start blender with `--python-console`, see the [user manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/advanced/command_line.html#python-options) for Python command line args.

Comment: the link no longer works.

Comment: A different path to the same resource: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html#python-options

Answer (score 0):

Blender has a [python console](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Extensions/Python/Console) built-in, you can change any section of the blender layout to a console.

[image]

You can also find an [addon here](http://www.blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?312821-Run-Script-in-PyConsole-%28Menu%29) that lets you execute a text block in the python console.

Comment: interesting add on that you linked in your answer, but overall this answer does not fit to my question. The solution is to start blender with --python-console.